# My state is not updating when typing on the input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

When i'm trying to type in the input element the state dosen't update. So i can't type anything in the input. I get no error code either. In the handleChange function the text variable is undefined when i log it to the console. But the value variable updates every single letter i type. But not as a whole sentence, the letters just overwrites them self.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function AddTodo(props) {
  const initialFromState = { text: "", isComplete: null, id: null };
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState(initialFromState);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!todo.text) return;
    props.AddTodo(todo);
    setTodo(initialFromState);
    console.log(todo);
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { text, value } = event.target;
    setTodo({ ...todo, [text]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto text-center">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="rounded flex">
        <input
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 mr-4 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          type="text"
          name="text"
          value={todo.text}
          onChange={handleChange}
          autoComplete="off"
          autoFocus={true}
          placeholder="Eg. Buy apples"
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddTodo;
```

I expect that what i'm typing to the input is stored in the state and that i can see what i'm typing. Next challenge is to see if the todo actually is stored and showed among the other todos. :) One step at the time.

Comment: What is `event.target.text`? I'm pretty sure that would be `undefined`, since you don't have a `text` attribute on your `input`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrong prop names in your `handleChange`, `text` should be `name`:

```
 const handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setTodo({ ...todo, [name]: value });
  };
```

Comment: Omg... i've been sitting to long with this. How can i missed that. Thank you so much. But now i got prop.addTodo(todo) is not a function. :/

Comment: Make sure you're passing that prop, also in your code it's spelled `props.AddTodo(todo);` with a capital letter.

Comment: You're right. Oh lord jesus :D I passed in the same prop AddTodo, which is this component. This is my first try in a React app. I think i'll take a step back a do it all over again to learn it better. Thanks for the help Clarity. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its supposed to be `name`, you do not have text attribute to target it.

`name='text'` attribute given use that.

```
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setTodo({ ...todo, [name]: value });
```